# Is there a way to create a re-usable base table definition in InfoSphere Data Architect?

Tags: schema, tools, ddl, scripting, infosphere-data-architect

Our company has chose to use [IBM's InfoSphere Data Architect (IDA)](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/optim/data-architect/) for data architecting regarding our data warehouse and data marts.

The data architects originally designed several "re-usable" tables for our marts. In other words a table like CUSTOMER_DIMENSION may reside structure-wise in more than one mart. Each mart will have their own copy of their data.

I believe to make things easy, they defined all the tables (dimensions and facts) within the same "schema" that they called DB2ADMIN within IDA.

Since a mart can only have one fact table, I have to look at the diagrams of the table relationships to the fact tables to determine which tables should get generated into a DDL file for a particular mart. As of right now each mart physically resides within its own schema within one database. So not only do I have to manually pick the tables for DDL generation, but I have to manually tweak each DDL file to override the schema. This is not ideal as it is an error-prone process.

Is there a way to have a "base" definition of a table and then inherit it or whatever into the real table within IDA? What I'm looking to do is have schema definitions within the tool same as what we have on our server. I would like only the applicable tables to show up within each schema (as a mart should be - one fact and only its dimension tables it cares about). But to save on work, I'd prefer if the table definitions were in one place. So the architects could make one change, but we could more easily generate our tables.

Is this possible? Are there any gurus with IDA out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, it appears that at least in the version we are currently using (7.5.3.0), that no such functionality exists. Marking this the answer for now, unless someone else discovers otherwise (including within a new version).